# php script get 25 image per second from android

Tags: php, android

I try to send 25 image/second to server. In my android app, i set it to send image every 40 milisecond, so every 1 second i will have 25 image was sent. But now with my php scrip, it cannot get continuosly image, it just get 1 image and i had to refresh website. This is my php script

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);


$path = "publib_html/"; 
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
$size = $_FILES['file']['size']; 

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$path.$name);
```

?>

How can i  fix it to get continuesly 25 image per second or do you have which blog write about it?

Thank in advance

Comment: You can crontab your php script in your server.

Comment: I still unclear, could you please tell me more detail

Comment: A crontab is a text file with a list of commands meant to be run at specified times. So you can add to this file your foo.php and run it every minute. I don't know if you can do it also every second. [Look at this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: Ok I read that the minimun interval time is of 1 minute. So you can do the same as I wrote and then in your php script `set_time_limit(60);
for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
    // send your pictures
    sleep(1);
}`